# Hide/Unhide sheets - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet containing 15 different sheets. I want a "main menu" sheet from where I can just click a button and then be redirected to the chosen sheet, while keeping all the other sheets hidden. From the chosen sheet I want to be able to go back to the "main menu" sheet again and still keep everything hidden. Thus, only one sheet will show at the time.

My problem is the following;
The VBA code that I use is working perfectly, but sometimes it shows the error 
[Run time error '1004': Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet'failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6BCZ.png)
, and when I go to debug it shows the following [debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvt3j.png).

As mentioned the code works "perfectly", but sometimes the run time error 1004 pops up. What am I doing wrong? The code is the following;

```
Sub Button8_Click()
Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "practice group - mtd" Then
            sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: That error can occur if you are trying to hide the last visibile sheet. Is Sheet3 the same as the sheet with name "practice group - mtd"?

Comment: Also, are all of your tabs "worksheets"? As opposed to charts/macros/dialogs etc. If memory serves, they are all "Sheet" objects, but they don't all have the visible property. Not 100% about this though.

Comment: @s.storm not sure where you are "redirected" to the sheet  ? I don't see any`Sheet("whatever_you_Selected").Activate` anywhere in the code you shared

Comment: one more question: where is the Sheet Selection ? user_form? Cell ?

Comment: When I run that vba code I am redirected to the sheet "practice group - mtd" and it hides everything else, BUT it gives me the error message (even though it runs fine). I am completely new to all of this, so I don't know what to do. I just want a "main menu" tab from where I can navigate to different sheets, and then navigate back to the "main menu" tab from the chosen tab :)

Answer (score 0):

A faster workaround to avoid looping all sheets:
keep the name of the visible sheet somewhere hidden in main menu sheet.
(in a hidden cell, with FIXED location).
Upon button click, if selection different than visible one, unhide selected, hide previous sheet, update main menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, and sorry for the stupid question, how do I do that exactly? I am pretty new to all this. What would the VBA code be then?

Answer (score 0):

Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Visible = False

Comment: This is not an answer. Also this is not even the correct answer to the PO question. Please delete it